# match full string which does not contain numbers,- and+

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a pattern for strings which have any other characters except

> +,[0-9],- and \

. 
Eg: +123-\ should not be matched
    +232aa should be matched

I tried this:
     `^[a-zA-Z?\§$%&=?{}\\]*$`

- a string like asdad$ is matched
- a string like +331234-44 is not
  matched which is what I want
- a string like 123asd or asdad123$ is also not matched
  but should me matched

I am not sure what I did wrong here

Comment: Your examples are confusing, why no match for `+123-\\`` and `+331234-44` and match for `+232aa`?

Comment: @Toto do you bless the rains down in Africa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
^.*[^+0-9\\-]+$|^[^+0-9\\-]+.*$
```

Here is a working demo:

https://regex101.com/r/xsvqkS/2

I think you have the `,` in your blockquote to separate the 'items' and it's not part of your item list.  I'm using a `[^ ... ]` as a negative character class.  So anything NOT in that list will match.  Note that the `\` needs to be escaped and I put the `-` hyphen at the end so it can't be confused as a range of characters.

I'm sure there is a more concise regex that can be written, but I usually lean on the side of being very readable.  That why it's easy to update down the road.

Comment: From OP: "`+232aa` should be matched" but your regex doesn't.

Comment: ah.. I misunderstood.  I was thinking "match" as in he's looping a list and a match happened, not the whole item now turns into a match.  I'll update.

Comment: try this instead `^.*[^+0-9\\\n-]+$|^[^+0-9\\\n-]+.*$|^.*[^+0-9\\\n-]+.*$` because I assume if OP says this is ok `+232aa` then also this is ok `+232aa232` to account for any presence of allowed character no matter the location in a single line.

Comment: @HadiFarah ah, you might be right.  Now that I re-read his question I'm not actually sure what he wants :)  Like is the data a list, or a huge text file?

Comment: I just assume 1 line text with break lines if none is specified. [My Regex](https://regex101.com/r/S7wz7h/1)

Comment: The issue is I have a table with phone numbers with some wired characters, after analysis the above mentioned pattern is what I have seen. That is the reason for the question